# Test results not showing when testing Node with Mocha

Tags: node.js, testing, tdd

I am following the book Jump Start Node.js and am starting to write tests with mocha. My test output should show something similar to:

```
3 of 3 tests failed:
1) exchange buy should add a BUY nockmarket order:
ReferenceError: exhange is not defined
```

But instead what I am seeing is:

```
npm install make test
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/make
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/test
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/make
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/test
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-font/0.0.2
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-font/0.0.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-font/-/ansi-font-0.0.2.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-font/-/ansi-font-0.0.2.tgz
make@0.0.0 node_modules/make

test@0.6.0 node_modules/test
└── ansi-font@0.0.2
```

Am I missing something very simple? My test suite is as follows:

## exchange.test.js

```
'use strict';

var assert = require('assert')
  , should = require('should');

var exchangeData = {};

suite('exchange', function() {
    test('buy should add a BUY nockmarket order', function(done) {
    exhangeData = exchange.buy(40, 100, exchangeData);
    exchangeData.buys.volumes[40].should.eql(100);
    done();
});

test('sell should add a SELL nockmarket order', function(done) {
    exchangeData = exchange.sell(41, 200, exchangeData);
    exchangeData.sells.volumes['41'].should.eql(200);
    done();
});

test('sell should produce trades', function(done) {
    exchangeData = exchange.sell(40, 75, exchangeData);
    exchangeData.trades[0].price.should.eql(40);
    exchangeData.trades[0].volume.should.eql(75);
    exchangeData.buys.volumes[40].should.eql(25);
    exchangeData.sells.volumes[41].should.eql(200);
    done();
});
});
```

## package.json

```
{
      "name": "nockmarket"
    , "version": "0.0.1"
    , "private": true
    , "dependencies": {
          "jquery" : "1.7.3"
        , "mocha": "1.3.0"
        , "should": "1.0.0"

    }
}
```

## Makefile

```
test:
    @./node_modules/.bin/mocha -u tdd
.PHONY: test
```

According to the books instructions I have Node installed correctly and I can run simple examples with no issues.

Any ideas would be very helpful.

Thanks,
T.

Comment: What are you running to get this error? A make script? Or are you just running `npm install make test`? Because if it's what you are running, that's the expected output.

Comment: I'm running npm install make test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NPM is the node package manager. If you're running

```
npm install
```

you're just installing the modules `make` and `test`, which is not what you want. If you want to run your tests, what you need to do is to run you make file

```
make -f your_make_file
```

, which is configured to run your `mocha` tests.

If your make file has a standard name (like `makefile` or `Makefile`, for example), you don't even need to specify it.